# Query builder: multiple AND act like an OR

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a many to many relation between  entities Content and Filter.
I would like to get all Contents which have the filters "1", "2" AND "3" (all three). My query gives me results as if I would use "OR, because I get a lot of contents which have only one of the three Filter.

My query:

```
public function getContentByFilters($categ, $filter, $filter2, $filter3){
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->leftJoin('c.filterfilter', 'f')
    ->where('f.idfilter = :filter_idfilter')
    ->setParameter('filter_idfilter', $filter)
    ->andWhere('f.idfilter = :filter_idfilter')
    ->setParameter('filter_idfilter', $filter2)
    ->andWhere('f.idfilter = :filter_idfilter')
    ->setParameter('filter_idfilter', $filter3)
    ->andWhere('c.contentCategorycontentCategory = ?2')
    ->setParameter(2, $categ)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $query;
}
```

Entity Content:

```
/**
 * Content
 *
 * * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="loic\ContentBundle\Entity\ContentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="content", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idcontent_UNIQUE", columns={"idcontent"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_id", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_content_content_category1_idx", columns={"content_category_idcontent_category"})})
 */
class Content
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idcontent", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idcontent;

.............
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="loic\FilterBundle\Entity\Filter", inversedBy="contentcontent")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="content_has_filter",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="content_idcontent", referencedColumnName="idcontent")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="filter_idfilter", referencedColumnName="idfilter")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $filterfilter;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->contentLinked = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->filterfilter = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->creationDate = new \DateTime();
}

.........

/**
 *
 * @return the \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getFilterfilter() {
    return $this->filterfilter;
}

/**
 *
 * @param
 *          $filterfilter
 */
public function setFilterfilter($filterfilter) {
    $this->filterfilter = $filterfilter;
    return $this;
}
```

}

Entity Filter:

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Filter
     *
     * * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="loic\FilterBundle\Entity\FilterRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(name="filter", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idfilter_UNIQUE", columns={"idfilter"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_filter_filter_category1_idx", columns={"filter_category_idfilter_category"})})
     */
    class Filter
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="idfilter", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $idfilter;

    ............


        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="loic\ContentBundle\Entity\Content", mappedBy="filterfilter")
         */
        private $contentcontent;

    .....

      /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->contentcontent = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
            $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
            $this->status = 1;
        }

    ......

        /**
         *
         * @return the \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getContentcontent() {
            return $this->contentcontent;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param
         *          $contentcontent
         */
        public function setContentcontent($contentcontent) {
            $this->contentcontent = $contentcontent;
            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: Change the names of your filter values: andWhere('f.idfilter = :filter_idfilter2') etc.  However this sort of logic makes no sense since f.idfilter is only going to have one value and will never match three different values.  Might need to rethink your logic.

Comment: Yes there is also a logic problem. Because even in SQL it doesn't work.
exemple : 
select c.name
from content c
left join content_has_filter cf on  c.idcontent=cf.content_idcontent
left join filter f on f.idfilter=cf.filter_idfilter
left join content_category cc on c.content_category_idcontent_category = cc.idcontent_category
where cf.filter_idfilter=1
and cf.filter_idfilter=2
and c.content_category_idcontent_category = 1

gives no result...
Any help ? :/

Comment: Think you will have to query for categs then write your own php filter.

Comment: So you think the only solution is to loop on filters and repeat the query x times (x = number of filters) ?
Weird that there isn't a way to do it directly no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to check for 3 filters, you need to `JOIN` 3 times as well. It is as if you had 3 different ManyToMany relationships and only want one row, that fits 3 specific requirements - only difference is, that you join the same table. Untested, but it should work like this

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->join('c.filterfilter', 'f1')
    ->join('c.filterfilter', 'f2')
    ->join('c.filterfilter', 'f3')
    ->where('f1.idfilter = :filter_idfilter1')
    ->andWhere('f2.idfilter = :filter_idfilter2')
    ->andWhere('f3.idfilter = :filter_idfilter3')
    ->andWhere('c.contentCategorycontentCategory = :category')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'filter_idfilter1' => $filter,
        'filter_idfilter2' => $filter2,
        'filter_idfilter3' => $filter3,
        'category' => $categ,
    ))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Inner join is probably better as you only want rows, that do fulfill these requirements. Also be aware, that using too many joins is usually considered bad practice and may slow down performance. Preferred solution is usually to construct a specific view instead of multiple joins.

Comment: You are welcome. If you do not have any other questions on this specific topic, please consider marking the answer as accepted